# Notification doesn't work in Android 12 and later

Tags: java, android

I have a music app, It used to work very well, but unfortunately, in Android 12 and later, it gets an error.
How can I fix it?

My java code:

```
reView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notify);
        Intent sendNotify = new Intent(this, Text.class);
        sendNotify.setAction(Fixed.ACTION.BASIC_ACT);
        sendNotify.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        during = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, sendNotify, 0);
        Intent sendPlay = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
        sendPlay.setAction(Fixed.ACTION.PLAY_ACT);
        PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                sendPlay, 0);
        reView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.togglePlay, pendingPlayIntent);
```

Comment: "it gets an error" -- what is the error? If you are crashing, please edit your question and post the entire stack trace of the crash.

Comment: In addition to what CommonsWare suggests, you should also google the error message. This will often lead to a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
You need to change your code as below:

```
 reView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notify);
        Intent sendNotify = new Intent(this, Text.class);
        sendNotify.setAction(Fixed.ACTION.BASIC_ACT);
        sendNotify.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        during = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, sendNotify,
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Intent sendPlay = new Intent(this, Notify.class);
        sendPlay.setAction(Fixed.ACTION.PLAY_ACT);
        PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                sendPlay, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ? PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        reView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.togglePlay, pendingPlayIntent);
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent